# How does slideUp() work in jQuery? I'm trying to make my own slideRIght()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have looked at the [source code in jquery for slideup](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js)...

```
// Generate shortcuts for custom animations
jQuery.each({
    slideDown: genFx("show", 1),
    slideUp: genFx("hide", 1),
    slideToggle: genFx("toggle", 1),
    fadeIn: { opacity: "show" },
    fadeOut: { opacity: "hide" },
    fadeToggle: { opacity: "toggle" }
}, function( name, props ) {
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( speed, easing, callback ) {
        return this.animate( props, speed, easing, callback );
    };
});
```

I understand that this is shorthand for functions, so I folllow through to GenFX

```
function genFx( type, num ) {
    var obj = {};

    jQuery.each( fxAttrs.concat.apply([], fxAttrs.slice(0,num)), function() {
        obj[ this ] = type;
    });

    return obj;
}
```

and then fxAttrs

```
fxAttrs = [
        // height animations
        [ "height", "marginTop", "marginBottom", "paddingTop", "paddingBottom" ],
        // width animations
        [ "width", "marginLeft", "marginRight", "paddingLeft", "paddingRight" ],
        // opacity animations
        [ "opacity" ]
    ],
```

but I just can't figure out how this code works, or how I would go about creating a slideLeft or slideRight that affects the width attribute of the HTML.

Comment: This is a better link for `slideUp`: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.2.6&fn=jQuery.fn.slideUp

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$('div').animate({ width: 'show' }); // slideLeft

$('div').animate({ width: 'hide' }); // slideRight
```

Demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bj4pm/).

Comment: I like this technique as it doesn't use jquery UI, but I am having real difficulties trying to get it to reverse in the other direction (slide right in this demo - try a slide right when it's hidden http://jsfiddle.net/bj4pm/4/ )

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same with `slideRight` as with [`slideUp`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.2.6&fn=jQuery.fn.slideUp):

```
$.fn.slideRight = function(options) {
    var s_opt = {
        speed: "slow",
        callback: null
    }

    $.extend(s_opt, options);
   return this.each(function() {
        $(this).effect("slide", null,
            s_opt.speed, s_opt.callback);
   });
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/eVUsH/

Comment: This one is pretty hard to read. You are allowing the user to pass options, but you have called an effect "slide". Where did that come from, and if I wanted to slide left, is that possible?